# assets, no thumbnails, no image on front end

Tags: assets

I'm using Assets 1.1.5 and EE 2.4 .  I can upload an image ok through Assets, but no thumbnail is created and the image does not appear on the front end.

The only difference I can see is that on the server, the owner / group is different when a file is uploaded through Assets than if a file is uploaded directly to the server.

Thanks,

Comment: If you upload an image via EE's Filemanager, are the thumbnails created then?

Comment: Hi Adris, thanks for your help.  To answer your question, it does, but we've found the issue.  The folder structure is a bit complicated and some permissions on folders were not set right after a server move.  Thanks again.